# Difference between Avro file format and bz2 compression in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I know that below are input and output format in the hive,

Text File.
Sequence File.
RC File.
AVRO File.
ORC File.
Parquet File.

When do we use bz2 compression and how are they different from hive file format? and when to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avro is a file format and BZ2 is a compression codec. These two are completely different things.

You can chose [file format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/FileFormats) and compression codec independently. Some file formats are using internal compression and have limitation on which codecs can be used. For example ORC supports ZLIB and SNAPPY codecs. And you can configure codec in table properties like this:

```
...
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
```

Or using hive configuration:

```
hive.exec.orc.default.compress=SNAPPY;
```

Read about ORC here: [ORC hive configuration](https://orc.apache.org/docs/hive-config.html)

[Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) supports SNAPPY and DEFLATE codecs.

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET avro.output.codec=snappy;
```

With textfile you can use any codec.

[BZ2 is not the fastest codec](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/hadoop-compression-choosing-compression-codec-part2) and can be used in cases when you do not have strict performance requirements. Read about compression on [Cloudera site](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_data_compression_performance.html).

What is important to understand here is that non-splittable compression is not always an issue if you are using splittable container. For example the whole file compressed with snappy is not splittable but ORC using SNAPPY internally is splittable because ORC is splittable.

Comment: Do we able to read data from BZ2 file in hive?, Because input file format is restricted like avro and parquet.

Comment: @Ganesh You can use it with test files(CSV, JSON), not with Parquet, Avro.